# Titan data corruption

Tags: cassandra, titan, nosql

I get an exception when calling `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge.getLabel` on some vertex edges :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find type for id: 630
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:200)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.vertices.TitanTypeVertex.getName(TitanTypeVertex.java:30)
        at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx$VertexConstructor.get(StandardTitanTx.java:321)
```

I can solve this issue by removing all vertex and start over, but we obviously don't want to do that in production.

This error seems to occur when there is a data corruption but I don't have any idea why it happens : I don't know if it's data which are corruped or type schemas.

Does anyone know the possible causes for this error/corruption and know who it can be repaired softly?

The backend I’m using is cassandra.

Comment: found a solution yet ?

Comment: Yes, and it's was hard.
I extracted all vertex into json while excluding which one throwing exception, And I whipe out the database an reload json in a fresh database. The result was 21 unknow vertex lost in the battle.

Comment: so did you also find the reason why data got corrupted. For me it happened when I made index on an already deployed cluster and changed that index's name later. Do you know what caused your data to corrupt? And if yes, do you know what is the safe way to do schema operations on titan such that it does not corrupt anything

Comment: No sorry I never known my be a problem with cassandra