# Error in saving Huge graph db in GraphSON format

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

I'm working on saving a huge graph-database with about 80 million nodes and 120 million edges(Stored in 3 Cassandra machines) in extended GraphSON format to the local file system. However once the file reaches 28 GB the gremlin shell is crashing always with this error :

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find type for id: 322
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.vertices.TitanTypeVertex.getName(TitanTypeVertex.java:30)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx$VertexConstructor.get(StandardTitanTx.java:321)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx$VertexConstructor.get(StandardTitanTx.java:291)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.vertexcache.GuavaVertexCa
```

Note : The purpose of saving to GraphSON format is to port it to the 0.5 version of Titan. I had already tried moving it to HDFS with Faunus based on this question [What are the methods to migrate millions of nodes and edges from 0.44 to 0.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793596/what-are-the-methods-to-migrate-millions-of-nodes-and-edges-from-0-44-to-0-5) i posted earlier , but it wasn't successful.

The method used to save the GraphSON file is : saveGraphSON after loading the graph with these parameters :

```
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=sve1,sve2,sve3
storage.port=9160
storage.batch-loading=true
storage.buffer-size=8196
storage.keyspace=dbgraph
ids.block-size=50000
cache.db-cache=true
cache.db-cache-size=0.5
```

Please can you provide me suggestions in saving the graph into GraphSON format successfully.

Comment: Could it be not because of large data, but maybe in process of migration, some data is corrupted. I usually get this exception when I have made changes in indexing and stuff on an already deployed cluster. This error goes away if I remove all the data and start fresh. See this issue too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996285/titan-data-corruption. From all these evidence it could be a possibility that the data is somehow being corrupted/not properly indexed and thus at the time of retrieval, they throw this error.